# ListView virtualization requires a valid ListViewItem to be provided by the RetrieveVirtualItem event or in the OnRetrieveVirtualItem method

Tags: c#

Can someone clear me where I am wrong in this code... I know there is some problem in `listView1_RetrieveVirtualItem` method but I couldn't correct it. I am getting this error:

> ListView virtualization requires a valid ListViewItem to be provided by the RetrieveVirtualItem event or in the OnRetrieveVirtualItem method.

Here is my code:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _fileInfoCollection = new Queue<ListViewFileInfo>();
    }

    private void GetFileInformation(string drive)
    {
        _fileInfoCollection.Clear();
        var directory = new DirectoryInfo(drive);
        var files = directory.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            _fileInfoCollection.Enqueue(new ListViewFileInfo() { FileName = file.Name, FilePath = file.FullName });
        }
    }

    private void listView1_RetrieveVirtualItem(object sender, RetrieveVirtualItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_fileInfoCollection.Count > 0)
        {
            ListViewFileInfo fileInfo = _fileInfoCollection.Dequeue();
            var listViewItem = new ListViewItem();
            listViewItem.Text = fileInfo.FileName;

            var listViewSubItem = new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem();
            listViewSubItem.Text = fileInfo.FilePath;
            listViewItem.SubItems.Add(listViewSubItem);
            e.Item = listViewItem;
        }
    }

    private void comboBoxDrive_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetFileInformation(comboBoxDrive.Text);
    }

    private Queue<ListViewFileInfo> _fileInfoCollection;


}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code using ListView virtual mode still lack some of important information.
Firstly, we need set value to **VirtualListSize** property of ListView.
Secondly, we need setup a cache value to retrieve ListItem correctly.

We should keep in mind the RetrieveVirtualItem event **always required return a ListViewItem**.

You can reference at here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.virtualmode%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

I have modified your code base on my assume, you can modify it following your idea. Hope this help.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private ListViewItem[] myCache; //array to cache items for the virtual list 
    private int firstItem; //stores the index of the first item in the cache

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _fileInfoCollection = new Queue<ListViewFileInfo>();
    }

    private void GetFileInformation(string drive)
    {
        _fileInfoCollection.Clear();
        var directory = new DirectoryInfo(drive);
        var files = directory.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
        myCache = new ListViewItem[files.Length];
        int temp = 0;
        foreach (var file in files)
        {

            _fileInfoCollection.Enqueue(new ListViewFileInfo() { FileName = file.Name, FilePath = file.FullName });

            ListViewFileInfo fileInfo = _fileInfoCollection.Dequeue();
            var listViewItem = new ListViewItem();
            listViewItem.Text = fileInfo.FileName;

            var listViewSubItem = new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem();
            listViewSubItem.Text = fileInfo.FilePath;
            listViewItem.SubItems.Add(listViewSubItem);
            myCache[temp] = listViewItem;
            temp++;
        }

        listView1.VirtualListSize = myCache.Length;
    }

    private void listView1_RetrieveVirtualItem(object sender, RetrieveVirtualItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (myCache != null && e.ItemIndex >= firstItem && e.ItemIndex < firstItem + myCache.Length)
        {
            //A cache hit, so get the ListViewItem from the cache instead of making a new one.
            e.Item = myCache[e.ItemIndex - firstItem];
        }
        else
        {
            //A cache miss, so create a new ListViewItem and pass it back. 
            e.Item = new ListViewItem();
        }
    }

    private void comboBoxDrive_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetFileInformation(comboBoxDrive.Text);
    }


    private Queue<ListViewFileInfo> _fileInfoCollection;
}
```

Comment: Hi.. I just used your code and it didn't throw any error but however the listview doesn't show any items. Is there anything else I need to correct ?

Comment: I have made a test my code. At my side it working as expected. I believe problem is another place. You should make sure the comboDrive return has slash \ symbol at the end of drive character. One more important thing your code just only list out the file not directory. So if there is not any file the list will blank. Hope this help.

Comment: No, I have debug the code and the list has 213 files. But, I don't know why it is not filling that listview. I have try this with simple folder containing 213 files. Is there any other places where i need to correct it.

Comment: Do you have set the View styles property of listView is Details?

Comment: Could you please check the myCache already contains list view items? And the last place you should check is e.Item = myCache[e.ItemIndex - firstItem] should be trigger correctly.

Comment: Thanks Toan Vo.. the problem is due to listView is Details. I changed that it works. But why it is giving problem when listView is set as Details.

Comment: I have take your code and paste into my example and press F5. It working as expected. I wonder why at your side cannot display. Hmm. I will send to you my code. Could you please send me your email address?

Comment: You can take reference here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.virtualmode.aspx.

Comment: ViewMode in Details is not a problem. You should check your environment as well as make sure you update latest service pack of windows and .Net framework.

Comment: Here is my email id: sanzbajracharya@hotmail.com
The code is working but doesn't work when the view style property of listView is Details...

Comment: Great, look like you got caching problem. :)

Answer (score 2):

I have had this issue a few times, and for anyone who is using the ObjectListView  (FastObjectListView) open source library like I am, or is just using a Virtual ListView with a datasource I found that the issue was not with the list or the data itself, it was with the source of the data.

It is hard to diagnose from the error you are given when using a virtual list, but when I changed my FastObjectListView to an ObjectListView (basically removing the virtual functionality) I was able to see the actual error causing the exception and it was that a view that had once existed no longer existed on my entity framework model.

Hope this helps someone as it had me scratching my head and googling the hell out of that useless error message.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete code..

```
 /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.listView1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ListView();
        this.columnHeaderIndex = ((System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader)(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader()));
        this.columnHeaderInformation = ((System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader)(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader()));
        this.comboBoxDrive = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // listView1
        // 
        this.listView1.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader[] {
        this.columnHeaderIndex,
        this.columnHeaderInformation});
        this.listView1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Bottom;
        this.listView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 24);
        this.listView1.Name = "listView1";
        this.listView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(551, 249);
        this.listView1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.listView1.UseCompatibleStateImageBehavior = false;
        this.listView1.View = System.Windows.Forms.View.Details;
        this.listView1.VirtualListSize = 500;
        this.listView1.VirtualMode = true;
        this.listView1.RetrieveVirtualItem += new System.Windows.Forms.RetrieveVirtualItemEventHandler(this.listView1_RetrieveVirtualItem);
        // 
        // columnHeaderIndex
        // 
        this.columnHeaderIndex.Text = "Index";
        // 
        // columnHeaderInformation
        // 
        this.columnHeaderInformation.Text = "Information";
        this.columnHeaderInformation.Width = 400;
        // 
        // comboBoxDrive
        // 
        this.comboBoxDrive.FormattingEnabled = true;
        this.comboBoxDrive.Items.AddRange(new object[] {
        "C:",
        "D:"});
        this.comboBoxDrive.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(-4, 0);
        this.comboBoxDrive.Name = "comboBoxDrive";
        this.comboBoxDrive.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(121, 21);
        this.comboBoxDrive.TabIndex = 2;
        this.comboBoxDrive.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.comboBoxDrive_SelectedIndexChanged);
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(551, 273);
        this.Controls.Add(this.comboBoxDrive);
        this.Controls.Add(this.listView1);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Form1";
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.ListView listView1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader columnHeaderInformation;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader columnHeaderIndex;
    private ComboBox comboBoxDrive;
```

Did i miss anything else in my code. Please ! check it. I am very curious to see the output.